# How do I run custom js function when angular js finished retrieving data from the server (and updating the dom)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code in the controller:

```
ViewCtrl.resolve = {
    /**
     * Fetching a user model from the backend to make it available to this controller.
     */
    user: ['$http', 'symfony2Router', function($http, symfony2Router) {
        return $http.get(symfony2Router.path('getUser')).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }]
};
```

And the following html template:

```
<span data-ng-repeat="item in user.articles">
    {{ item.title }}
</span>
```

The question is - how can I run a piece of js code, only after the dom has been altered by angularjs, and now has a span per each article the user has ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to only specific interpolation changes (in your case, user.articles) you could set a $watch listener for it in your controller:

```
$watch('user.articles.length', valueChanged);
```

And if you want to run some code only after DOM is changed:

```
var timeout;

function valueChanged () {
  if (!timeout) {
    // only run doStuffWhenDOMChanged when the $digest loop is finished and call stack is empty:
    timeout = $timeout(doStuffWhenDOMChanged, 10);
  }
}

function doStuffWhenDOMChanged() {
  //do stuff here...
  timeout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your `$timeout` to wrap your `piece of js code`. Then the code will be delayed to the next round of execution. At that time, the DOM is updated already.